Change DataValidation to Cancel on Google Sheets from edited google Form
So here is a quick run down - we use Google Workspace for a lot of our stuff here in the office. One of those things is email and cloud storage of course. However we also use a shared google calendar for time off, and a form used for the requests.
The form as some of you all may know already takes in the data into a Google Sheet and records it. That is all working fine, in fact I used an Array on the sheet to perform 2 functions. 1 to associate the persons email and first name together, as a lot of our employees tend to type First and Last name, sometimes just their first name and so forth, so filtering didn't make it easy. So using the array, I have it basically changing the name field on the sheet to their first name matched on their company email address.
Same with the supervisors, so we didn't have 5million if statements!
Now my next task is on the Google Apps script side, haven't had too much success with this part, and this is where I'm asking for help. I would like to have it that when an Employee submits a request to cancel their time off request, that it changes the data in Column K (Approval status column) [which uses Data Validation and drop down] to being back to blank or status cleared. I've tried numerous times and haven't gotten anywhere with it. The script would be looking for the modified response (they're supposed to use the "Edit Response" from the email they receive once they submit their request.
My current code sets.
code.gs - Uses onEdit Trigger
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 

  // EVENT VARIABLES 
  let row = e.range.getRow(); 
  let col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); 
  let n = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
  let em = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
  let sd = sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue().toLocaleDateString();
  let ed = sheet.getRange(row,6).getValue().toLocaleDateString();
  let tl = sheet.getRange(row,8).getValue();
  let sem = sheet.getRange(row,10).getValue();
  let rs = sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue()

  let projectName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();   

  if ( col == 11 && cellValue == "APPROVED") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: em,
        cc: sem + ',' + 'REDACTED EMAIL',
        subject: 'Your ' + projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
        htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>"+'Your ' + projectName + ' (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=GREEN>APPROVED</b></u> by ' + user + '.'
  }); 
  }; 
  if ( col == 11 && cellValue == "DENIED") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: em,
        cc: sem,
        subject: 'Your ' + projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
        htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>"+'Your ' + projectName + ' (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=RED>DENIED</b></u> by ' + user + '.' + "<br//>" + 'Reason: ' + rs 
  }); 
  }; 
  if ( col == 11 && cellValue == "PENDING") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: em,
        cc: sem,
        subject: 'Your ' + projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
        htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>"+'Your ' + projectName + ' (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=BLUE>PENDING</b></u> by ' + user + '.'
  }); 
  }; 
    if ( col == 11 && cellValue == "CANCELED") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: em,
        cc: sem + ',' + 'REDACTED EMAIL',
        subject: projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
        htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>"+'Your (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=ORANGE>CANCELED</b></u> by ' + user + '.'
  }); 
  }; 
}


SortResponses.gs
function sortResponses() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  sheet.sort(5, true);
}

Copy.gs
function Copy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  // Copy and paste operations
  spreadsheet.getRange('M3:Q500').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('M1:Q1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  
  // Update names based on email addresses
  updateNamesBasedOnEmails();
}

// Function to update names based on email addresses
function updateNamesBasedOnEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var arraySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Array");
  
  // Get data from Form Responses 1
  var emailRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C"); // Adjust if necessary
  var emailValues = emailRange.getValues();
  
  // Get data from Array sheet
  var arrayRange = arraySheet.getRange("A:B").getValues();
  var lookupMap = {};
  
  // Create lookup map from Array sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayRange.length; i++) {
    lookupMap[arrayRange[i][0]] = arrayRange[i][1];
  }
  
  // Update column B with names based on emails
  for (var j = 0; j < emailValues.length; j++) {
    var email = emailValues[j][0];
    var name = lookupMap[email] || ""; // Default to empty string if no match
    sheet.getRange(j + 2, 2).setValue(name); // Update column B
  }
}

OnEditCancel.gs
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'); // Adjust if your sheet name differs
  let responses = e.values; // This contains an array of form responses
  
  let row = sheet.getLastRow(); // Get the last row where the form response was added
  
  // Assuming the "Type of Leave" is in column H (8th column in sheet)
  let typeOfLeave = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();

  // Check if the type of leave is 'Cancel'
  if (typeOfLeave == 'Cancel') {
    // Clear the approval status in Column K (11th column)
    sheet.getRange(row, 11).clearContent();
    Logger.log("Leave type 'Cancel' detected, clearing approval status at row " + row);
  }
}

I'm hoping someone here has an answer and can help, coding is not my strong point/suit. I did a lot of this through reading, trying different things and hate to admit it, even using ChatGPT, but nothing seems to work.
I have tried multiple versions of the OnEdit code.gs and OnEditCancel scripts. I'm at a loss here.
What I'm expecting is that the Column K status would change to a blank or as if an option wasn't selected.

I'm guessing that you are expecting that the onEdit trigger will fire when you submit the form.  Unfortunately that is not correct.  The onEdit only fires on user edits.

The form works just fine other than the "Cancel" part. It's the Cancel I need to have working next and cannot for the life of my figure it out.

Are you expecting for the form submit to generate an onEdit trigger?

I have 4 different triggers... onEdit (code.gs), (on Form submit) onFormSubmit, On open (Copy.gs), and On Open (sortReponses.gs) - basically the OnEditCancel.gs is the onFormSubmit trigger

I'm trying to figure how to help you, help me. This is not my specialty at all, one of our managers here does not understand that an IT Admin is not a programmer.. Lol
So here is the thing...
User submits Vac request for say 3 days... It get's approved by whoever their supervisor is. They then decide to cancel, they hit the Edit responses in the return email and then select Cancel on the form. From there the data is recorded to the sheet with "Cancel" chosen, it's at this point I would like the column K to change from "approved" to either Canceled or back to as it nothing was selected.

I have asked a simple question do you expect the onEdit trigger to fire when the form is submitted and changes the linked sheet.  If you do then that won't work because it only fires on user edits not edits from other scripts or formulas.  The current question is too broad for this forum.   Perhaps you should get a hold  of the original programmer.

Lol there is no original programmer for this as it was originally scripted out by me using articles here and there and ChatGPT to backup what I've read and attempted to make work.

Okay so now I know that you are the programmer.  So what action triggers the onEdit function?

The onEdit would be triggered by whichever supervisor changes the K column from  (Data Validation column) to Approved, Denied, or Pending. When they change to one of those, it then triggers the email out to our HR person and the employee of the change.

Okay.  Thank you for that.  In order to get that to work you will have to creat an installable trigger because simple trigger cannot perform functions that require permission like MailApp.sendEmail().  Do you know how to create an installable trigger?

I do not, but I'm sure I could figure that out.

You can create it programmatically or manually through the ui. Do not name it onEdit().

In addition to creating an installable onEdit trigger like onMyEdit(e) you can also consider rewriting your code to something similar to this:
function onMyEdit(e) {
  let sh = e.range.getSheet();
  let [projectName, n, em, , sdv, edv, , tl, , sem, , rs] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 12).getValues().flat();
  let sd = sdv.toLocaleDateString();
  let ed = edv.toLocaleDateString();
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if (user) {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 11) {
      if (e.value == "APPROVED") {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: em,
          cc: sem + ',' + 'REDACTED EMAIL',
          subject: 'Your ' + projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
          htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>" + 'Your ' + projectName + ' (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=GREEN>APPROVED</b></u> by ' + user + '.'
        });
      };
      if (e.value == "DENIED") {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: em,
          cc: sem,
          subject: 'Your ' + projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
          htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>" + 'Your ' + projectName + ' (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=RED>DENIED</b></u> by ' + user + '.' + "<br//>" + 'Reason: ' + rs
        });
      };
      if (e.value == "PENDING") {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: em,
          cc: sem,
          subject: 'Your ' + projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
          htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>" + 'Your ' + projectName + ' (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=BLUE>PENDING</b></u> by ' + user + '.'
        });
      };
      if (e.value == "CANCELED") {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: em,
          cc: sem + ',' + 'REDACTED EMAIL',
          subject: projectName + ' request has been reviewed',
          htmlBody: n + ',' + "<br//>" + "<br//>" + 'Your (' + tl + ') scheduled for ' + sd + ' to ' + ed + ' has been <b><u><font color=ORANGE>CANCELED</b></u> by ' + user + '.'
        });
      };
    }
  }
}

I tried to restrain myself from simplifying it too much more so that it would continue to look like your original code so that you can continue to support it but by eliminating the separate getValue()'s it will run much faster with a single getValues(); I think that statement is called an array literal assignment you can try to look it up if you want to learn more about it.  I'm sure someone will review my answer and let you know if I'm wrong.
As we work our way through your issues we may be required to go to a chat room  but if you stick with me I'll stick with you until you surpass my knowledge and then you can take what you have and ask another question and someone smarter than I can help you some more.

Thanks for the help. I'm currently experiencing another issue now that I'm working through. A permissions issue with the mail.app which I'll get figured out, but currently it seems to be on Google Workspace end, because even saving scripts is erring out on me.

Cooper - Thank you for all of your help. Nothing seems to be working. If it's not one thing it's another. I'm going to give up on this project for now, I'm sure there is another way to do this. But I think it's the fact that K3 down is "Data Validation" that its causing the headache here.

So the issue is that it cannot do what we were wanting to do. However I was able to add in the script to highlight the row (into an offending color) when it's updated to "Cancelled" This prompting the supervisor or team lead to look at it and move along

I don't see anything in that script that can't work what is it that you think you found that will not work.

It was after reaching out to Google Workspace support and speaking with one of their software cloud engineers. (only took them forever to respond to me) They basically said what we're looking to do is not possible at the moment. He did not break it down as to why, but said that we're not the only company that's reached out to them and asked how or why it doesn't work.
